# Uninstalled program will not re-install because dependencies now not met?

Tags: dependencies, reinstall

Ubuntu 20.04

I have used the (ancient - 2006) Catalog management software Gwhere since Ubuntu 18. Recently, on starting, it had "forgotten" the directory where my data was stored and I had to open it every time I used the software.

So I thought I would uninstall (using Synaptic package manager) and reinstall the software using the downloaded .Deb file.

However, now the package installer tells me a Dependency is not satisfied (libglib1.2) despite Synaptic telling me I have libglib2.0 installed.

Can anyone point me to how I could get Gwhere working again - like it was 20 minutes ago before I tried to fix a really minor issue with my sledghammer. I can't ask a more focused question because I don't even know where to start looking.

Thanks for any help,
Neil

Comment: FYI:  If it was a Ubuntu 18 system like Ubuntu Core 18, as the *year* products are *snap* only, all releases run the same applications - and on upgrade only the base OS changes since no applications require change.  This is different to the *year.month* or *deb* based products; so your reference to Ubuntu 18 makes no sense, and is likely wrong (you likely meant a 18.04 or like system which is a different product; Ubuntu has had *year* format releases meaning *snap* only since 2016).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [search on repology.org](https://repology.org/project/gwhere/versions) this application was last available for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

To fix possible package errors run commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then to reinstall GWhere you need to download it by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gwhere/gwhere_0.2.3.dfsg.1-4_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./gwhere_0.2.3.dfsg.1-4_amd64.deb
```

---

Also you may be interested in trying [Tellico](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/tellico) or [GCStar](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcstar/gcstar_1.7.1+repack-1_all.deb).